# Stream YouTube Audio over wifi network

Tags: wireless, sound, android

I want to have my YouTube video playing on my computer, and I want to listen to the audio on my android phone, mostly because I cannot be bothered taking off my earphones and plugging them into the computer (at work).

How do I stream ALL audio output to android phone?

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called Soundwire for Android.  I have never used it and I am not endorsing it.  However, it claims to be able to do what you want.

"SoundWire lets you send any music or audio ("what you hear now") from your Windows or Linux PC to your Android mobile devices."

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.georgie.SoundWireFree&hl=en